# How can I achieve this two-column layout with Tailwind?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I need to create three divs positioned like below:

[image]

Green div should be 75% width and red divs should have 25% width and 50% of height, placed in column. And everything should be responsive.

Right now I have something like here:

```
          <div className="w-full">
            <div className="w-3/4 float-left">
              
            </div>
            <div className="w-1/4 float-right">
              <div id="red-one"></div>
              <div id="red-two"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

but it not this same as i expected :/

can someone tell me how to do this?

thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Floats aren't a modern layout technique. Don't use them for that. Also, your markup should have `class` attributes for purposes of this question, not `className`.

Answer (score 2):

**Oldish** option (**see nowdays below that one**) :you can use and mix the **table-layout** display and regular **block** display via tailwind **class**

Possible example

```css
/* your scrennshot's borders */
div div {border:solid red;}
div.table-cell{border-color:green}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table w-full p-2">
  <div class="table-cell w-3/4 p-2">hello</div>
  <div class="p-2 ml-2"> the</div>
  <div class="p-2 mt-2 ml-2">world</div>
</div>
```

**any draw back ?**
yes, if both content of the rights side div are shorter than the content of the left one, it wont fill the column

---

**nowdays** option: `grid`

Advised example:

```css
div div {border:solid red;}
div div:first-child{border-color:green}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid grid-cols-4 p-2 grid-cols-2 gap-2">
  <div class="col-1 col-span-3 row-span-2 p-2">hello</div>
  <div class="col-2 p-2"> the</div>
  <div class="col-2 p-2">world</div>
</div>
```

**drawbacks ?** none, <del>but you will have to create your own class to set the grid-template-colums property to match your columns's widths</del> as commented by @bqardi

> Container: grid grid-cols-4 and green div: col-span-3 row-span-2? No need to create own class

Comment: Container: `grid grid-cols-4` and green div: `col-span-3 row-span-2`? No need to create own class...

Comment: @Bqardi thanks, i'm not a tailwind user , just gave a quick look at the doc. You may edit my answer or post yours , i'll delete mine then

Comment: no no, you gave good answers, just wanted to add that we could achieve the grid solution with pure tailwind.

Comment: @Bqardi okay, so i did update with your comment ;)